# Variable not working in a GSP Tag, but working in normal Text

Tags: grails, spring-security, gsp

I want to give the logged in User the Possibility to edit his User account with a Quick Link.

For this I created a Link using the correct GSP Tag, and I want to pass the User Id from the Spring Security UserDetails Object, using the correct Helper.

The Problem is that this works, when I am in the GSP Tag, like after Edit my User, but not where I really need it, in the id attribute.

```
<g:link controller="user" action="show" id="${sec.loggedInUserInfo(field: "id")}">
    Edit my User ${sec.loggedInUserInfo(field: "id")}
</g:link>
```

Expected:

```
<a href="/Backoffice/user/show/1"> Edit my User 1 </a>
```

Wrong Result:

```
<a href="/Backoffice/user/show"> Edit my User 1 </a>
```

The UserDetails Class the Security Tag Lib is accessing is here:

```
   import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GrailsUser
   import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority

   class UserDetails extends GrailsUser {
       final String displayName
       final String email
       final String gravatarImage

   ...
```

The id is defined as Object in the GrailsUser Base Class.

class GrailsUser extends User {

```
private final Object _id

    ...
```

}

And will be encoded as HTML here:

```
/**
 * Renders a property (specified by the 'field' attribute) from the principal.
 *
 * @attr field REQUIRED the field name
 */
def loggedInUserInfo = { attrs, body ->

    // TODO support 'var' and 'scope' and set the result instead of writing it

    String field = assertAttribute('field', attrs, 'loggedInUserInfo')

    def source
    if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
        source = determineSource()
        for (pathElement in field.split('\\.')) {
            source = source."$pathElement"
            if (source == null) {
                break
            }
        }
    }

    if (source) {
        out << source.encodeAsHTML()
    }
    else {
        out << body()
    }
}
```

Funny thing is: This works. But I really would like to use consistent gsp Syntax for Links, and I would like to understand why the Code posted on top does not work.

```
<a href="${createLink( controller : "user", action : "show", id : sec.loggedInUserInfo(field: "id"))}">Edit my User</a>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like wrong quoting - you need to escape `"` inside of `id="..."`. To keep it simple, try using `field: 'id'` instead of `field: "id"`.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked. Interesting that IDEA does not display the obvious error ...

Comment: I reported a good bunch of bugs to IDEA with Grails - they get fixed lightning fast.

Answer (score 0):

You required to pass the id as parameter, you are just assigning id to your link..

```
<g:link controller="user" action="show" params="[id:${sec.loggedInUserInfo(field: "id")}]" id="${sec.loggedInUserInfo(field: "id")}">
    Edit my User ${sec.loggedInUserInfo(field: "id")}
</g:link>
```

Use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see the exact rendered html of g:link...